# ArangoDB: upgrade from version 3.10 to 3.11.6 basic query cannot be resolved

Tags: arangodb

I just migrated from version 3.10 to 3.11.6.
By the web interface I tried to run a basic query for testing and the query is still not resolved 10mn later.

I loaded road graph of Andorra (https://michaelmathieu.net/resources/andorra_data.zip).

When I run the following query, everything is fine (resolved in less than 1ms):
FOR path IN OUTBOUND K_SHORTEST_PATHS 'points/1' TO 'points/20' ways LIMIT 1 RETURN path

But when I add the OPTIONS to specify the weightAttribute, it doesn't respond:
FOR path IN OUTBOUND K_SHORTEST_PATHS 'points/1' TO 'points/20' ways OPTIONS { weightAttribute: 'cost', defaultWeight: 1000 } LIMIT 1 RETURN path

Never had this problem before with previous version.

Here is the execution plan:

```
{
"plan": {
    "nodes": [
        {
            "type": "SingletonNode",
            "dependencies": [],
            "id": 1,
            "estimatedCost": 1,
            "estimatedNrItems": 1
        },
        {
            "type": "EnumeratePathsNode",
            "dependencies": [
                1
            ],
            "id": 2,
            "estimatedCost": 74.91332290800307,
            "estimatedNrItems": 1,
            "database": "andorra",
            "graph": [
                "ways"
            ],
            "isLocalGraphNode": false,
            "isUsedAsSatellite": false,
            "defaultDirection": 2,
            "directions": [
                2
            ],
            "edgeCollections": [
                "ways"
            ],
            "vertexCollections": [
                "ways"
            ],
            "collectionToShard": {},
            "optimizedOutVariables": [],
            "isSmart": false,
            "isDisjoint": false,
            "forceOneShardAttributeValue": false,
            "tmpObjVariable": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "1",
                "isFullDocumentFromCollection": false
            },
            "tmpObjVarNode": {
                "type": "reference",
                "typeID": 45,
                "name": "1",
                "id": 2
            },
            "tmpIdNode": {
                "type": "value",
                "typeID": 40,
                "value": "",
                "vTypeID": 4
            },
            "options": {
                "parallelism": 1,
                "produceVertices": true,
                "maxProjections": 5,
                "minDepth": 1,
                "maxDepth": 1,
                "weightAttribute": "cost",
                "defaultWeight": 1000,
                "type": "shortestPath"
            },
            "indexes": {
                "base": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "type": "edge",
                        "name": "edge",
                        "fields": [
                            "_from"
                        ],
                        "selectivityEstimate": 0.5408036454018227,
                        "unique": false,
                        "sparse": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            "shortestPathType": "K_SHORTEST_PATHS",
            "pathOutVariable": {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "path",
                "isFullDocumentFromCollection": false
            },
            "startVertexId": "points/1",
            "targetVertexId": "points/20",
            "fromCondition": {
                "type": "n-ary and",
                "typeID": 62,
                "subNodes": [
                    {
                        "type": "compare ==",
                        "typeID": 25,
                        "excludesNull": false,
                        "subNodes": [
                            {
                                "type": "attribute access",
                                "typeID": 35,
                                "name": "_from",
                                "subNodes": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "reference",
                                        "typeID": 45,
                                        "name": "1",
                                        "id": 2
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "value",
                                "typeID": 40,
                                "value": "",
                                "vTypeID": 4
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "toCondition": {
                "type": "n-ary and",
                "typeID": 62,
                "subNodes": [
                    {
                        "type": "compare ==",
                        "typeID": 25,
                        "excludesNull": false,
                        "subNodes": [
                            {
                                "type": "attribute access",
                                "typeID": 35,
                                "name": "_to",
                                "subNodes": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "reference",
                                        "typeID": 45,
                                        "name": "1",
                                        "id": 2
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "value",
                                "typeID": 40,
                                "value": "",
                                "vTypeID": 4
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "LimitNode",
            "dependencies": [
                2
            ],
            "id": 3,
            "estimatedCost": 75.91332290800307,
            "estimatedNrItems": 1,
            "offset": 0,
            "limit": 1,
            "fullCount": false
        },
        {
            "type": "ReturnNode",
            "dependencies": [
                3
            ],
            "id": 4,
            "estimatedCost": 76.91332290800307,
            "estimatedNrItems": 1,
            "inVariable": {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "path",
                "isFullDocumentFromCollection": false
            },
            "count": true
        }
    ],
    "rules": [],
    "collections": [
        {
            "name": "ways",
            "type": "read"
        }
    ],
    "variables": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "path",
            "isFullDocumentFromCollection": false
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "1",
            "isFullDocumentFromCollection": false
        }
    ],
    "estimatedCost": 76.91332290800307,
    "estimatedNrItems": 1,
    "isModificationQuery": false
},
"cacheable": true,
"warnings": [],
"stats": {
    "rulesExecuted": 43,
    "rulesSkipped": 0,
    "plansCreated": 1,
    "peakMemoryUsage": 0,
    "executionTime": 0.0002441999999973632
},
"error": false,
"code": 200
}
```

Comment: Can you share the query execution plan?

Comment: did you try to re-index?

Comment: @ShaharShokrani re-index is a new requirement with v3.11?

You have all the info to reproduce the problem, in your environment my example works?